# JavaScript How to make a global object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, global

How do I make a global object in JavaScript? This is some example code

```
    function main() {
        window.example {
            sky:"clear",
            money:"green",
            dollars:3000
        }
    }
```

So why can I not access the object outside the function?

Comment: Did you forget an assignment operator?

Comment: `window.example = {};`

Comment: @zerkms `window` makes a variable global.

Comment: There's no `window` in Node, you're probably looking for `module.exports`, or `global`

Comment: `window` is a property that does not need to be used. ie: `window.document.getElementById()`. You are really assigning the `example` Object to `window` in your example, which will work, so you don't have to type window, but top level variables are `Global`.

Comment: If you're doing this browser-side then this is basically common practice; but if you're doing this Node.js side please don't do global Node variables. `require()` and the like exist for a good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the `=`

```
window.example =  {
   sky:"clear",
   money:"green",
   dollars:3000
}
```

In `node` window is `undefined`, if you really want to use `window` as a `global variable` make sure to declare it as

```
var window = {}
```

**Not sure why you would do that**

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not setting anything.

```
function main() {
    window.example = {
        sky:"clear",
        money:"green",
        dollars:3000
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only that. Hint: it's node.js

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: The `=` sign to assign window.example.

Comment: It still isn't working. It says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: example`

Answer (score 0):

Not a property of window and Global:

```
var globalExample = {
  sky: 'clear',
  money: 'green',
  dollars: 3000
}
// don't have to even use `var` with top level variables - It's a good practice anyways though
function main() {
  this.example = globalExample;
}
var nm = new main;
nm.example.sky = 'grey';
console.log(globalExample.sky);
```

Constructor style.